# How to find if target path in custom url rewrite exists in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

how to check if the target path for custom url is present in the url rewrite table in magento 2.

I had created custom url rewrite using following code.

```
$urlRewriteModel = $this->_urlRewriteFactory->create();
$urlRewriteModel->addData(
            [
                'entity_type' => \Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Adminhtml\Url\Rewrite::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOM,
                'entity_id' => 0,
                'request_path' => "abc",
                'target_path' => "xyz/index/view/id/".$displayText['videoData']['id'],
                'redirect_type' => \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\OptionProvider::PERMANENT,
                'store_id' => 1,
                'description' => null,
                'is_autogenerated' => 0,
                'metadata' => null
            ]
        );
$urlRewriteModel->getResource()->save($urlRewriteModel);
```

This data add when i save any new record in from admin. if i edit same record then also it will call. so i want to know if that target record is already ther in magento 2. if yes delete and add again using above code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
protected $_urlRewrite;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlRewrite $urlRewrite
) {
    $this->_urlRewrite = $urlRewrite;
}



    $UrlRewriteCollection=$this->_urlRewrite->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('target_path', 'path_to_check')
    $deleteItem = $UrlRewriteCollection->getFirstItem(); 
    if ($UrlRewriteCollection->getFirstItem()->getId()) {
        // target path does exist
        $deleteItem->delete();
    }
```

Comment: i want to delete if target path exists

Comment: Please check updated answer. I didn't test.

Comment: Upvote the answer so it will be helpful to other also.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer is great, but using interfaces is always the best

Try using the following code:

```php
public function __construct(
   \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
) {
   $this->urlFinder = $urlRewrite;
}

...

$data = [
   \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => 'requst_path',
   \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::TARGET_PATH => 'target_path',
   \Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => 'storeId',
];

$url = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData($data); // returns null if not found
```

I hope this answer will help someone in the future.